# Ht access Redirect For URL's with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect a page For eg:
`mysite.com/productdetails.html?id=234` to `mysite/productdetails.php?id=234`
I wrote an htaccess rule like

```
RewriteRule productdetails.html?id=([^/.]+)*$ productdetails.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But its not working??
Can anyone help me please....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work perfectly. add this line to your htaccess file

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule productdetails.html$ productdetails.php [L]

Inside productdetails.php, get the id like

```
  $id=$_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you have a comma rather than a period here:

```
mysite/productdetails,php?id=234
```

Comment: @dominic its my typing mistake.... and the redirecting depends on rewrite rule.. right???

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `RewriteRule` only matches `REQUEST_URI`, it doesn't match `QUERY_STRING`.

You can use this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews    
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule productdetails\.html$ productdetails.php [L]
```

`QUERY_STRING` is automatically carried over to new URI.

Comment: I tried your code but it's redirecting me to BAD URL. Its redirect me to home/sitename/public_html/productdetails.php/

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule productdetails\.html$ productdetails.php [L]`

Comment: @ anubhav same result :-(

Comment: What URL did you use to test? What is path of .htaccess? Half baked/incomplete information is the only reason for this super simple rule to not to work.

Comment: uaeautoparts.com/productdetails.html?id=123 to uaeautoparts.com/productdetails.php?id=123 & I have placed my htaccess file in the root directory.. Is this info enough?? @anubhav